# insert into mysql with PDO - error

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reads='241', picsWay='63526'' at line 1' in /home/asd/public_html/asdd/proccesNewsAdd.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /home/asd/public_html/asdd/proccesNewsAdd.php(25): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/asd/public_html/asdd/proccesNewsAdd.php on line 25

```
<?
    // Post datas
    $date               = date('d.m.Y');
    $postNewsTitle      = $_POST['newsTitle'];
    $postNewsContent    = $_POST['newsContent'];
    $writer1            = 'Alen Sky';
    $reads1             = 241;
    $picsWay1           = 63526;

    $insertNewsAdd = $conn -> prepare('INSERT INTO news SET date=:date, title=:title, content=:content, writer=:writer, reads=:reads, picsWay=:picsWay');
    $insertNewsAdd -> execute(array(
        'date'      => $date,
        'title'     => $postNewsTitle,
        'content'   => $postNewsContent,
        'writer'    => $writer1,
        'reads'     => $reads1,
        'picsWay'   => $picsWay1,
    ));
?>
```

Comment: Maybe because reads is a reserved keyword of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reads` is a reserved word in MySQL. If you want to use it as a column name you'll have to wrap it in backticks everywhere you use it in an SQL statementlike this:

```
`reads`
```

[MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)